# Assign content automatically to specific user

Tags: nodes, users

I added a new roles - technical support and management. Added several user to that role.

Created new content type called Claim Report contain fields ( title, body, area ).

What I want to achieve is, when authenticated user create new content claim report, select specific area and save, it will automatically shown to specific technical support user account sort by area.

Ex :

techspp1 - area 1

techspp2 - area 2

techspp3 - area 3

When authenticated user create content and choose area1, that specific content only shown in techspp1 account page, choose area2 shown in techspp2 account page only.

Then techspp1 reply / give solution and the user claim content get updated with that solution and get status solved / on-progress.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Should the specific technical support user accounts be allowed to edit the claim report contents?

Comment: no, the technical support can not change or edit the claim report...the tech support can only reply for the solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Node Access Rules](https://drupal.org/project/node_access_rules) to achieve this goal. Using this you can create rule to access that particular content having some condition as per your requirement.

Comment: is there any video tutorial for this module ?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're looking for is a creating a publishing workflow using a workflow module like [Workbench](https://drupal.org/project/workbench). Check out this YouTube video to see what it does: [Part 1: Creating a Publishing Workflow in Drupal 7 Using Workbench](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nqWLrxH_4M)

Comment: but the content from the authenticated user automaticly published and can not be edited by the technical support...can this be achieved using workbench ?

Comment: Yes. Workbench allows you to set the permissions on who can create, read, update, or delete certain contents or content types depending on their role, permissions, etc. I think the best way to approach this is to write down who can create / read / update / delete which, download and install the module, watch the video, and play around with it.